# How to pass bert embeddings to an LSTM layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, bert-language-model

I want to do sentiment analysis using bert-embedding and lstm layer.
This is my code:

```
i = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
x = bert_preprocess(i)
x = bert_encoder(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name="dropout")(x['pooled_output'])
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, dropout=0.2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name="output")(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(i, x)
```

When compiling this code I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected 
ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 768)
```

Is the logic of my code correct? Can anyone please correct my code?

Answer (score 1):

From bert like models you can expect generally three kinds of outputs (taken from [huggingface's TFBertModel documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bert#transformers.TFBertModel))

- `last_hidden_state` with shape (batch_size, sequence_length, hidden_size)
- `pooler_output` with shape (batch_size, hidden_size)
- `hidden_states` with shape (batch_size, sequence_length, hidden_size)

`hidden_size` is 768 above..

As the error says, the output from dropout layer lacks 3 dimensions (essentially the bert_encoder layer because dropout layers do not change tensor shape) and has only 2 dimensions.

```
x = bert_encoder(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name="dropout")(x['pooled_output'])
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, dropout=0.2)(x)
```

So if you are planning to use an LSTM layer after the bert_encoder layer, you would need a three dimensional input to the LSTM in the form of `(batch_size, num_timesteps, num_features)` hence you would have to use either the `hidden_states` or the `last_hidden_state` outputs instead of `pooler_output`.
You will have to choose between the two depending on your objective/use-case.